# Can a Number field in a managed package be changed to a Currency field of the same precision and scale?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, schema, push-upgrade

Such a change can be made using `sfdx force:source:push`, presumably because there isn't any risk of data loss (mentioned in [Notes on Changing Custom Field Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&type=5)).

Can this change be packaged and orgs successfully upgraded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this in a throwaway namespace and packaging org. After adding a `Number(16,2)` field to a 1GP managed package and performing a managed release, I was **unable** to change the field type from the UI or via the Metadata API.

Comment: This [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/modifying_custom_fields.htm) seems to confirm it, but I was initially thrown off with the fact it only mentions Salesforce Classic...But, the [parent page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/publish_upgrades.htm) says LEX which makes me think it just hasn't been updated.